# Present value and discount function

Tags: finance

What deposit made today will provide for a payment of $ \$1000$ in $1$ year and $ \$2000$ in $3$ years, if the effective rate of interest is $0.075$.
Answer is $\$2540.15$

I have calculated $d=0.069$
by using $i=\frac{d}{1-d}$

Then by using $A(3)=A(0)(1-d)^{-3}$, I don't get the answer

Comment: You are neglecting the interim $\$1000$ payment.  For the last two years interest accrues on a reduced amount.

Comment: I am not understanding. Could you please be more precise @lulu

Comment: I'll post a calculation.  Also: check your discount factor...for small interest rates $d\sim 1-i$

Comment: With $\$2540.15$ initial investement and an interest rate of $0.075$ you need to be a magician to receive $\$1000$ in just $1$ year.

Comment: @JimmyR.,I understand your logic, but that is called the discount function. Please google it, you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $X$ is the deposit, and after one year you have a payement of $1000$, the residual value after this year is 
$$
X_1=X(1+i)-1000
$$
that after two years becomes:
$$
\left(X(1+i)-1000\right)(1+i)^2=2000
$$
solve for $X$ and you have the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_0$ denote the initial amount, and $A_i$ the amount amount $i$ years.  We have $$A_1=A_0(1+i)-1000\;\;\;\;\;\;A_2=3000=A_1(1+i)^2$$  Substituting for $A_1$ we see that $$3000=(A_0(1+i)-1000)(1+i)^2=A_0(1+i)^3-1000(1+i)^2\implies A_0=\frac {3000+1000(1+i)^2}{(1+i)^3}$$  Plugging in $i=.075$ yields $$A_0\sim\$3345.1143$$

Note:  I see that the problem was revised after I posted.  It is, of course, easy to change $\$3000$ to $\$2000$ in the above.